# Is it possible to produce current in thermocouple for a domestic purpose?

Tags: thermodynamics

If a two dissimilar metals a connected with different temperature an end is produced between two ends..if it is possible to produce large amount of current.

Comment: Early space probes were powered by a generator that consisted of a heat-producing lump of radioactive material and a thermocouple array.

Comment: *"it is possible to produce large amount of current"* - what is *large* in this case?

Answer (score 0):

the voltages and currents available via thermoelectric junctions are very small. it is possible to string many junctions together in series to obtain larger voltages, but the current remains small... In Soviet-era Siberia, a finned metal "chimney" with a bunch of thermoelectric junctions in it was designed to sit atop a kerosene lamp to use the waste heat from it to produce enough electric power to operate a small radio, but this is the only example I know of where what you suggest was actually put into practice.

Comment: Today you can go to your local outdoor/camping store and find gear to charge your cell phone from your camping stove.

Comment: those probably contain semiconductor junctions rather than bimetallic thermocouple junctions. they are better at generating electricity but still have very low efficiency... I'd like to try designing a little closed-cycle heat engine that would run on a stove flame for this purpose- in my copious free time ;-)

Comment: The physics principles are all the same, so its good. Skutterudites seem to be the "hot" thing now in thermoelectrics...

Comment: what's the composition of a skutterudite?

Comment: They are ugly alloys, things like (La,Ba,Ga,Ti)1(Fe,Co)4Sb12 for p-type and (Yb,Ca,Al,Ga,In)0.7(Co,Fe)4Sb12 for n-type. While semiconducting, one generally would not consider them for other types of devices.

Comment: OMG they do sound ugly- that's a very apt description!

Answer (score 0):

There is a company that actually sells modules for just that purpose: their website is http://kryothermtec.com/thermoelectric-modules-for-power-generation.html

They give a set of [hints](http://kryothermtec.com/assets/dir2attz/TGM%20hints.pdf) on how best to achieve good efficiency. One of the key aspects is that the "cold" side of the element must be really cold (much colder than the hot side) for this to work with any kind of efficiency. Since the company is in Siberia, I suppose they have a ready supply of "coldness"... The figure 5 in the linked document shows that if the hot side is at 200°C and the cold side is at 30°C, then their 4x4 cm module will generate 12 W of power. That's enough to charge up your cell phone [at a decent clip](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/10/02/comparing-iphone-8-charging-speeds-with-fast-charge-wireless-and-more).

Comment: $12~\rm W$ should be plenty to charge a phone quickly. Looking at my phone charger, it only outputs $2~\rm A$ at $5~\rm V$ for a total of $10~\rm W$.

Comment: @Chris you are right - I updated my answer.

Comment: the coefficient of performance for a thermoelectric generator is typically quoted as the ratio of the electric conductivity (which needs to be high as possible) to the thermal conductivity (which you want to be as low as possible). high electrical conductivity is required to minimize I^2R heat generation in the junction and low thermal conductivity is required to prevent the junction from thermally short-circuiting itself. from a materials science standpoint, it's a hard problem to satisfy both requirements simultaneously.